# How to redirect domain to a new server while leaving blog traffic on the older server

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I've developed a new shopping site for a friend on my server (**server 2**). My friend currently has a wordpress blog hosted on **server 1**. I tried transferring it to my server under `/blog` but ran into a bunch of problems with server configuration. So rather than mess around with that I wanted to leave the blog where it is if possible?

Blog is currently in main dir eg **domain.com** on **server 1**.

How can I direct **domain.com/blog** traffic to old server and **domain.com** shop traffic to new server?

Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Where is the shop located?

Comment: using subdomain you can point it on the old server and main domain on the new.
so: blog.domain.com -> old server
domain.com -> new server
it's only an idea but it works

Answer (score 0):

If you keep on using the same domain for blog and shop, you are bound to receive all requests on the same server. (One domain = one IP)

- You can point **domain.com** to **server 2** and use **server 2** as a proxy to **server 1** to respond some of the requests. That way **server 2** will answer `/blog` requests by querying **server 1**, where the blog is really installed.

  If you use Apache2, this can be set up easily via mod_proxy as explained here : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass
- The other solution (probably easier) is to use subdomains and point **blog.domain.com** to **server 1** and **domain.com** to **server 2**.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Follow these steps:

1) Go to database and choose wp_option table. Change site_url whatever you want in wordpress.

2) Go to "General" in setting option in admin panel and change both url given in box.

that's it.